# Terminal window displays odd text after being resized

Tags: macos, terminal

If I open a terminal window, and then shrink it as far left as possible, and then enlarge it again, it displays some odd text, including some of the letters in my hostname:

[image: Error Screenshot]

Any way to fix this?

Note: I'm guessing this is a bug, since when I go fullscreen, and then go back to a window, it goes back to normal and won't happen again.

Update: Some other weird stuff happens when I resize the window from using commands within the window.

Comment: It's a bug caused by Terminal's automatic text rewrapping combined with your shell's SIGWINCH rerendering. Nothing you can really do about it except to clear your terminal (Cmd+K).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug caused by Terminal's automatic text rewrapping combined with your shell's `SIGWINCH` re-rendering. If you just want to clear the corrupted text, you can use `Edit->Clear All` (default shortcut  <kbd>⌘</kbd>   +  <kbd>K</kbd> ) to clear the window, leaving only the prompt.